# constructor param not available in init

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I try to use one Zend_Form for update and create and want to switch both through a param. But my approach using the constructor did not work. When I debug this part the property is set correctly but in the init()-method it is null again.

Maybe I do not understand the Zend_Form approach. Can you help me? Where is the error?

**Form Class:**

```
class Application_Form_User extends Zend_Form {
    const CREATE = 'create';
    const UPDATE = 'update';

    protected $_formState;

    public function __construct($options = null, $formState = self::CREATE) {
        parent::__construct($options);

        $this->_formState = $formState;
        $this->setAction('/user/' . $this->_formState);
    }

    public function init() {

      $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);

    if ($this->_formState == self::CREATE) {
            $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
            $password->setRequired()
                    ->setLabel('Password:')
                    ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim());
    }
[..]
```

**Usage in controller action:**

```
$form = new Application_Form_User();
$this->view->form = $form->render();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init()` method is called inside `parent::__construct($options)`. Try this:

```
public function __construct($options = null, $formState = self::CREATE) {
    $this->_formState = $formState;
    parent::__construct($options);

    $this->setAction('/user/' . $this->_formState);
}
```

I switched the first two lines of the constructor.